# Laravel password recovery template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following code which sends a passowrds recovery mail:

```
public function recovery(Request $request)
    {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->only('email'), [
            'email' => 'required'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()) {
            throw new ValidationHttpException($validator->errors()->all());
        }

        $response = Password::sendResetLink($request->only('email'), function (Message $message) {
            $message->subject(Config::get('boilerplate.recovery_email_subject'));
        });

        switch ($response) {
            case Password::RESET_LINK_SENT:
                return $this->response->noContent();
            case Password::INVALID_USER:
                return $this->response->errorNotFound();
        }
    }
```

Which I found out uses the following template: `resources/views/auth/emails/password.php`

which is an empty file.

How I can access the token from this template?

Isn't there any built-in view to use from laravel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function in your questions doesn't return a `view`.

Also, I'm unfamiliar with that path to the view that is in your question. Which version of Laravel are you using?

Anyhow, you can get the reset `token` from the DB, just like any other value in the DB. E.g. from a controller that is returning a view:

```
$user = User::find(Auth::id());
$remeber_token = $user->remember_token;
return view('to_your_view.blade.php', compact('remember_token');
```

And then in the view file:

```
{{ $remember_token }}
```

This will output it, no need to use `echo` or anything.

But, again, the function you pasted into your question is not a function that is returning a view, so I'm not sure where to tell you to put the above code.

As for your questoin about Laravel having an in-built view for 'this', in Laravel 5.3, at least, the view I assume you want will be within `resources/views/auth/passwords/'.

Comment: It doesn't return a view, I make a POST request to this URL. this template is the email template sent to the users. I use laravel only as server(not client)

Comment: Oh ok. Still, though, it's being 'pulled in' via a controller? Does it not work if you paste in my code into the controller and then this is the view file `{{ $remember_token }}` ?

Comment: the `remember_token` in my `users` table is empty, but I have another table named `password_resets` with `email | token | created_at`. And yeah, this method is in my AuthController